# Trying to use setInterval() but error occurs

Tags: php, jquery, setinterval

I'm trying to load testdata.php and automatically refresh every 10 seconds. But it doesn't work. What's wrong with my code? I'm still new at web programming so please bear with me

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0   /jquery.min.js">
$( "#data" ).load( "http://localhost/testdata.php" );
</script>    
</head>

<body>

<div id="data"></div>    

</body>
window.setInterval(function(){
/// call your function here
}, 10000);      
</html>
```

Comment: There's no script tag around your code. That will be treated as a normal text.

Comment: I already added but still doesn't work

Comment: Because your setInterval function is empty, so it does nothing?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so there was a few space in the URL of jquery which means the browser couldn't load it. The load wasn't inside the interval and your javascript code should be inside a script tag. And be sure you call jQuery when the document is ready.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function(){
        $( "#data" ).load( "http://localhost/testdata.php" );
        setInterval(function(){
            $( "#data" ).load( "http://localhost/testdata.php" );
        }, 10000);  
    });   
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="data"></div>    

</body> 
</html>
```

Edit: Added a line to load the data when the dom is ready and then set the interval.

Comment: @Newboy11 Do you get any error? Check the console with the dev tool of your browser.

Comment: no errors in apache error log. doesn't load anything.

Comment: @Newboy11 check if `testdata.php` contains anything at all. And by dev tool I meant the dev tool that you can open in your browser with F12 so you can check if the script is failed or not.

Comment: I tried running testdata.php alone and it works @nergal

Comment: I got an error in dev tool *SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' *ReferenceError: $ is not defined *The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. @Nergal